# Creating an Instance in an AppDomain from a System.Type

Tags: c#, plugins, types, appdomain

I am trying to create an Instance in an AppDomain. So I can create a seperate AppDomain for each of my plugins and dispose of them correctly when I close them using the Unload method.

So far I have an IEnumerator of all my plugins and I cycle through them executing the following code.

```
Type temp = (Type)enumerator.Current;
AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain(temp.FullName);
object obj = ad.CreateInstance(temp.Assembly.FullName, temp.FullName);
```

But it crashes on the third line saying that it could not load file or assembly.

Previously I used:

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance((Type)enumerator.Current);
```

but found I could not dispose of the plugins correctly by calling base.dispose() meaning service calls were left open and code would continue to execute when the service returned.

Is it possible to create an app domain from a type?

Comment: Why are you doing this yourself instead of using maf?

Comment: It is legacy code which I have built a plugin for but upon building a plugin I found that the plugins are not correctly disposed of. To be quite honest with you though I don't know a lot about maf apart from what it stands for

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok so I found my mistake. It should have read:

```
object obj = ad.CreateInstanceFrom(temp.Assembly.Location, temp.FullName);
```